# Are the conjectural values of $H_{k}:=\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}p_{n+k}-p_{n}$ available somewhere?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

The question is in the title. It can be found on the current Polymath 8b project page that one expects to have $H_{1}=2$, $H_{2}=6$, $H_{3}=8$, $H_{4}=12$ and $H_{5}=16$ but I'm interested in larger values. Could someome tell me where I can find them?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I know. Actually I ask the question because I'm presentely working on establishing the equivalent asymptotic equality $H_{m}=(1+o(1))m(1+Harmonic(m))$, where $Harmonic(m)$ is the $m$-th harmonic number and I want to check out if this is rather accurate or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know values for larger $k$, except for $k\le 342$ computed by Thomas Engelsma (see the tables here: http://math.mit.edu/~primegaps/), but the Hensley-Richards results imply that
$$
H(k) ≤ (1+ o(1))\, k\log (k),
$$
and the Brun and Titchmarsh results imply 
$$
H(k) ≥ (1/2−o(1))\, k\log (k).
$$
It is actually expected that $H(k) = k \log k + O(k)$. Numerically,
$H(k) ≤ k\, \log (k) + k$ appears to hold for all sufficiently large k.